# Why should I want to avoid object instantiation in code and use the Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

See, when we are explaining **Spring Framework** to newcomers, we would say we want to avoid new object instantiation in code and Spring will inject dependencies. Thereby we will explain **IoC and DI.**

My question is:

> **"Why do we want Spring instantiation compared to traditional instantiation?"**

Is the answer better object management?  Or simply to take advantage of IoC and DI?
Please list down concrete answer with explanations.  I am wondering what might be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, Springs dependency injection supports and encourages use of good programming practices, like using interfaces (by-type injection) and modularizing things to different layers instead of writing huge classes (if you've ever seen "good old everything in Servlet"-webapps, you probably know what I mean). Since injecting a service- or DAO-object can be done easily, like with just a simple annotation (like @Autowired) or via XML-configuration, modularizing applications is fast and easy.

I'd stay it's still **not** useful to handle instantiation of **everything** via Spring, you can still create objects with *new*, if the objects are such that Spring doesn't need to be aware of them or you just use them somewhere for moving data between layers etc.

Some people have complained about the xml-configuration with Spring. With Spring 3.0, the new annotations make coding and simple configurations very fast, and your XML-configuration file needs only to contain the actual configuration of the software, not all the injections and "configuration" that actually never changes.. as an example, a few years back, we built a relatively simple in-house application with Spring 2.5 (it did have some annotations already, but we didn't use them), and the size of xml-configuration files grew to over 1000 lines in total very fast. Currently, we have a project with Spring 3.0 and the XML file contains only 100 lines, the stuff that actually needs to be configurable after building the project.

Comment: Great! Btw,Is it something related to object management..? Better handling of objects with GC

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I don't think using or not using Spring has much effect on how the GC runs, but I'd guess things like scoping beans as singleton objects when only one instance is ever needed reduce the need for GC runs. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes

Answer (score 7):

I think spring is better than direct object instantiation because with spring configuration is clearly separated from the other code. This makes the components loosely coupled. Due to loose coupling it is very easy to replace/modify one component without affecting others. This makes the code *maintainable* and more importantly *testable* leading to better quality software.

Comment: Rightly told... Testablity of code is really important when it comes to Sw quality. Initially, I have struggled to test the code with JNDI.

Answer (score 1):

Because this make you focus on developing components, and frees you from developing the boiler plate code to set these components up in ONE way.

By using Spring, everyone can take your application, and replace components with own implementations, like an own authentication provider, without interfering with the rest of the application.

In addition it frees you from writing explicit configuration file handling, because the Spring configuration IS the application configuration.

Spring is very nice for large apps to be deployed and used by many.

Answer (score 1):

Use it sparingly. IOC is great for test-driven development, as it is easy to replace a component with a 'test' component.

It is important to understand exactly what component will be in your application.
IOC is not meant to replace all uses of instantiation.

Comment: "IOC is not meant to replace all uses of instantiation." Yes It is a important message.